# Creating a symlink doesn't work. How do I create it?

Tags: macos, iterm, zsh, symlink

##### OS version:

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.4
BuildVersion:   21F79
```

##### Command Line Interface:

```
zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)
```

#### Steps to reproduce

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ ln -sf whatever_exist whatever_you_want
ln: whatever_you_want: Operation not permitted
$ sudo ln -sf whatever_exist whatever_you_want
ln: whatever_you_want: Operation not permitted
```

I don't know what else to do. I would love anything else.

Comment: What's the rationale for wanting to access system binaries by alternative names? Please update your question if you can.

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/bin` is in the Monterey Signed Sealed Volume. It cannot be modified, even by the root user. See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secd698747c9/web for more info on the SSV. It's there to prevent the system being tampered with.

You can check whether a folder is in the SSV by using `diskutil apfs list` to display all the APFS volumes, and noting which ones are tagged as sealed. Generally there will be one volume's snapshot mounted at `/` which is sealed. Unsealed volumes such as `/System/Volumes/Data` will be the ones where user modifiable data reside.

You can check where a particular folder is by eg. :

```
% cd /usr/bin
% df ./
Filesystem     512-blocks     Used Available Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk3s1s1 1942700360 17243704 220253880     8%  348619 1101269400    0%   /

% cd ../local 
% df ./   
Filesystem   512-blocks       Used Available Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk3s5 1942700360 1689972040 220245304    89% 2814601 1101226520    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
```

As suggested in the comments, a better practice is to create the symlink somewhere else in the `$PATH`, such as `/usr/local/bin`, that should be there by default and is included exactly for this purpose.

```
% cd /usr/local/bin
% ln -sf /usr/bin/my_random_binary random_binary_linked
```

Comment: Almost certainly, along with this answer, you are better served with putting whatever you think you need to override something in `/usr/bin` with into another directory and prefixing that directory to your bath.

Comment: Yes, exactly what `/usr/local/bin` is for...